# What algorithm theory would I use for searching one full record in one big file which contains 100 millions records?

Tags: algorithm, search

Recently, I encountered an interview question,

> One log file contains 100 millions records,how to design efficient searching text algorithm for  compromising the memory usage and time cost.
>
> Per record format is: timestamp(8digits)\tid_number(15digits)\trecording_content
>
> Given the keyword(exp: the id_number or the timestamp), you have to return the complete line record info. The prefix 8 digits of per id_number is same, the prefix 6 digits of per timestamp is same.

I want to use the binary-tree related tree algorithms. Later,I googled some answers,Some recommend use the inverted indexing searching. But I have no idea for compromising the memory and time cost, Any ideas?

Comment: You've missed the point of the interview question.   It's not just about being able to name a few algorithms.   It's about how you reason about the problem, and decide what a solution needs to do - which sets the scene for picking algorithms, file structure (e.g. is it reasonable to assume the file is sorted, or is it necessary to sort it?), etc etc. What if you don't have enough memory to load a large number of entries into memory?

Comment: From the context, it seems like the question writer means something like “minimizing”. Perhaps the writer was thinking of “compressing”? Not really meaningful, but they might not have understood the ways that the word is used.

Comment: I'm guessing "compromising" meant "trading off", i.e. "finding an appropriate compromise between".

Comment: You can "Map" the file.. or map sections of it and search that way?

Answer (score 2):

If I were asked this question, I would start by asking questions to find out more about the problem domain. Some starting questions:

- Are the records in any particular order?
- Are the records all the same length, or variable length?
- Is there a definite range of record lengths?

It doesn’t sound like an index would be useful in this context (a log file), so I won’t discuss index-related issues.

For a log file, it seems likely that the timestamps would be in order. This would allow you to use binary search, possibly complicated by variable-length records.

If the records are added at regular intervals, such that the timestamp is a more-or-less linear function of the offset within the file, you can probably improve on binary search, by estimating based on linear interpolation — google **interpolation search**.